# cudaMalloc3D - Simple Example

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm just trying to compile a very easy example from the Nvidia Programming Guide which shows how to use cudaMalloc3D to allocate 3D data on the device.

This is the code I'm using, which gets compiled without any errors. Also `cuda-memcheck` runs without errors. I'm using a graphics card with CC 3.0.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float PixelType;

__global__ void extract_patches_from_image_data(cudaPitchedPtr devicePitchedPointer,     dim3 image_dimensions)
{
    // Test
    printf("HELLO - PLEASE PRINT THIS\n");

    // Check image dimensions
    printf("Current x: %d\n", image_dimensions.x);
    printf("Current y: %d\n", image_dimensions.y);
    printf("Current z: %d\n", image_dimensions.z);

    // Get attributes from device pitched pointer
    char     *devicePointer  =   (char *)devicePitchedPointer.ptr;
    size_t    pitch          =   devicePitchedPointer.pitch;
    size_t    slicePitch     =   pitch * image_dimensions.y;

    // Loop over image data
    for(int z = 0; z < image_dimensions.z; ++z)
    {
         char *current_slice = devicePointer + z * slicePitch;


        for(int y = 0; y < image_dimensions.y; ++y)
        {
            PixelType *current_row = (PixelType *)(current_slice + y * pitch);

            for(int x = 0; x < image_dimensions.x; ++x)
            {
                PixelType current_element = current_row[x];

                printf("Current element: %d\n", current_element);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // Set up test data
    PixelType image_data[3][3][3] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};
    dim3  image_dimensions = dim3(32, 32, 32);

    // Allocate 3D memory on the device
    cudaExtent volumeSizeBytes = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(PixelType) * image_dimensions.x, image_dimensions.y, image_dimensions.z);
    cudaPitchedPtr devicePitchedPointer;
    cudaMalloc3D(&devicePitchedPointer, volumeSizeBytes);

    // Kernel Launch Configuration
    dim3 threads_per_block = dim3(32, 32, 1);
    dim3 blocks_per_grid = dim3(32, 1, 1);
    extract_patches_from_image_data<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(devicePitchedPointer, image_dimensions);
}
```

My question now is: Why is there no output written to the console? It appears that the kernel is never called, but I cannot figure out why.
I tried using Eclipse Nsight, and also writing my own makefile which looks like this:

```
main: main.cu Makefile
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o main main.cu --ptxas-options=-v --use_fast_math --compiler-options -Wall
```

Comment: One more minor question: I had to cast `char *devicePointer = (char *)devicePitchedPointer.ptr;` this to `char`, in the programming guide it's not used. Anyone can tell my if this is a known error in the programming guide code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing call:
`cudaFree(devicePitchedPointer.ptr)`

Why do I need this for the printf's to work?.....

Comment: You need it because it implicitly carries a device synchronization (ie. it forces the kernel to finish before it proceeds with the free operation).  Without any device synchronization, your kernel gets launched *asynchronously* and immediately returns control to the host code.  The host code exits the application at that point and tears down the plumbing for `printf` to connect to stdout.  You could do the same with `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` at the end of your `main` routine.  The free is not actually necessary and will happen anyway at application termination.

Comment: Oh sure....didn't think about that kernels are asynchronous. THANK you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `image_dimensions` variable is declared in the host memory but is used in the kernel function. You have to copy this variable from host to device so that the device function can execute properly.